# Print does'nt work inside a loop (even though it is indented???)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

So I'm working on this code that has alot of loops in it and loops inside of loop and I need it to print stuff while inside certain loops, the code is supposed to work, it doesn't show any errors and the Run finishes, only that it ignores the printing...

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

csvdata = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Aviad Glav\Desktop\פרויקט גמר חלק ב'\Arc\israel_crime_2019.csv")
print("Welmcome to the Crime Analyzer Helper.")
#time.sleep(2)
print("Please wait while I load your CSV file containing the crime data.")
#time.sleep(1)
print(".")
#time.sleep(1)
print("..")
#time.sleep(1)
print("...")
#time.sleep(1)
print("Thank you for waiting, I have loaded your CSV file.")
print("        ")
#time.sleep(2)
print("What would you like to do next? :")
print("1. See the most dangerous city in General?")
print("2. See the most Secure city?")
print("3. See the city with the most fraud?")
print("4. See the city with the most assaults?")
print("5. See the city with the least public order?")
print("6. See the city with the most traffic violation?")
inx = input("Please insert the index: ")

CityNames = csvdata['name'].tolist()
Total = csvdata['total'].tolist()
Secure = csvdata['security_off'].tolist()
Assaults = csvdata['against_person'].tolist()
Public = csvdata['public_order_off'].tolist()
Traffic = csvdata['traffic_viol'].tolist()

if inx == 1:
    max_value = Total[0]
    max_inx = 0

    for i in range(len(Total)):
        if Total[i] > max_value:
            max_value = Total[i]
            max_inx = i
            break
    print("The city with the highest crime rate is:", CityNames[max_inx], ".")
    print("It had ",max_value,"total crime incidents in 2019.")

elif inx == 2:
    most_secure = Secure[0]
    most_inx = 0

    for i in range(len(Secure)):
        if Secure[i] > most_secure:
            most_secure = Secure[i]
            most_inx = i
            break
    print("The most secure city is:", CityNames[most_inx], ".")
    print("It had ", most_secure, "security offenses reported in 2019.")
```

As you can see, even if the operator chooses either 1 or 2, it's supposed to print the answer but the output of the code is:

```
Welmcome to the Crime Analyzer Helper.
Please wait while I load your CSV file containing the crime data.
.
..
...
Thank you for waiting, I have loaded your CSV file.
        
What would you like to do next? :
1. See the most dangerous city in General?
2. See the most Secure city?
3. See the city with the most fraud?
4. See the city with the most assaults?
5. See the city with the least public order?
6. See the city with the most traffic violation?
Please insert the index: 1
```

It just ignores the print statements inside the loops...
Please help!

Comment: I don't see any prints inside a loop, do you mean inside the `if` statement? Is there an outer loop you have omitted?

Comment: I ask the user to choose an option, and then I used "if", "elif" and "else" in accordance to the option the user chose, inside that "if" there's a "for" and inside it another "if" and that last "if" gives me a certain index that I use to display a value from the CSV.
What I'm not sure about is where the print need to be, nothing I tried worked so far..

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `input` function returns a string - [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

In your code, you are comparing a string to an int this is why the condition is not matched.
You can convert the input from the user to int before checking the choices:

```
...
inx = input("Please insert the index: ")
try:
    inx = int(inx)
except ValueError:
    # You should handle the wrong input format here 
...
```